# Detailed derivation of Multiplicative and Additive Holts & Winter triple exponential smoothing forecasting variance

Tags: mathematical-statistics, forecasting, references, econometrics, exponential-smoothing

I'm not able to found any website or textbook or scientific paper with the detailed derivation of of Multiplicative and Additive Holts & Winter triple exponential smoothing forecasting variance...

Any help/reference would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in my 2008 Springer textbook (https://robjhyndman.com/expsmooth/), and in this paper: https://robjhyndman.com/publications/predint/